# odoo 12 - Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-12

I've been having this error for 3 days. Help me please. I've also installed libsass. Before this odoo was working perfectly but I have been having this problem for a few days now. I have uninstalled and installed odoo several times. 
Thanks

```
http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:3745
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined
    at computeFloatOuterWidthWithMargins (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:3745:73)
    at _adapt (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:3744:461)
    at Object.initAutoMoreMenu (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:3738:533)
    at Class.start (http://localhost:8069/web/content/353-85cee96/web.assets_backend.js:850:189)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as start] (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:3538:488)
    at http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:3684:52
    at http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:802:681
    at fire (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:796:299)
    at Object.add [as done] (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:797:467)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/content/352-afaa597/web.assets_common.js:802:649)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: this error not js error

Answer (score 1):

Run this command

For linux:    `sudo pip3 install libsass==0.12.3`

For windows:   `pip3 install libsass`

Answer (score 0):

Clearing my browser localStorage and sessionStorage fixed this for me.